# Unexpected if else behaviour

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, web-deployment

I am working on a website which is constructed on mvc framework.
The problem isn't related to mvc or web development but rather I feel it is a general programming issue. So I have a if and else block which is behaving unexpectedly.

**Code**:

```
class table {
    constructor(datatypes, header, data, customfunctionsindex, customfunctionstype, customfunctions) {
        this.datatypes = datatypes;
        this.header = header;
        this.data = data;
        this.customfunctions = customfunctions;
        this.customfunctionsindex = customfunctionsindex;
        this.customfunctionstype = customfunctionstype;

    }
}
var data= new table(["label", "label", "input", "input", "input", "label","select", "button"],
    ["Saletype", "Service", "Quantity", "Discount", "GST", "Amount", "Employee", "Remove"], [],
    [2, 3, 4, 6], [function () {}, "null", "null", "null"],
    ["onchange", "onchange", "onchange", "onclick"]);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.header.length; i++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(i);
            var element = document.createElement(data.datatypes[i]);
            element.id = data.header[i] + (table.rows.length - 1);
            if (data.datatypes[i] == "label") {
                console.log(data.datatypes[i]+i);
                element.innerHTML = data.data[i];
                element.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(134 198 244)";
                element.style.color = "white";
                element.style.borderRadius = "0";
            }
            if (data.datatypes[i] == "input") {
                console.log(data.datatypes[i]+i);
                element.value = data.data[i];
                element.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(134 198 244)";
                element.style.color = "white";
                element.style.borderRadius = "0";
            }
            if (data.datatypes[i] =="select")
            {
                console.log(data.datatypes[i]+i);
                for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = employees[i].name;
                    option.value = employees[i].name;
                    element.appendChild(option);
                }
                element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                element.style.borderRadius = "10px";
                element.style.color = "white";
            }
            else {
                console.log(data.datatypes[i]+i);
                element.innerHTML = data.data[i];
                element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                element.style.color = "black";
                element.style.borderRadius = "0";

            }}
```

**Output in Console**

[image: Output in Console]

as you can see in the o/p file I have attached the else block is executed after the if block.
The o/p label0 is observed 2 times .On inspection I found that the first one is from if block corresponding to label but the second one is from else block , both happening for i=0. how can this be possible or have I done something wrong?

Comment: You might have forgotten to make all of the inner blocks `else if` rather than `if`. The `else` is only attached to the `if` before it rather than everything in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `else` statement is not fallback to all the `if` statements. but only for the last `if` statement i.e `if (data.datatypes[i] =="select")`. Add `else if` statements like so

```
            if (data.datatypes[i] == "label") {
                console.log(data.datatypes[i]+i);
                element.innerHTML = data.data[i];
                element.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(134 198 244)";
                element.style.color = "white";
                element.style.borderRadius = "0";
            }
           else if (data.datatypes[i] == "input") {
                console.log(data.datatypes[i]+i);
                element.value = data.data[i];
                element.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(134 198 244)";
                element.style.color = "white";
                element.style.borderRadius = "0";
            }
           else  if (data.datatypes[i] =="select")
            {
                console.log(data.datatypes[i]+i);
                for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = employees[i].name;
                    option.value = employees[i].name;
                    element.appendChild(option);
                }
                element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                element.style.borderRadius = "10px";
                element.style.color = "white";
            }
            else {
                console.log(data.datatypes[i]+i);
                element.innerHTML = data.data[i];
                element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                element.style.color = "black";
                element.style.borderRadius = "0";

            }
```

I would suggest `switch case` for this scenario

```
Switch (data.datatypes[i]) {
   case 'label':
   ...
   break;

   case 'input':
   ...
   break;

   case 'select':
   ...
   break;

   default:
   ...
}
```